# Principle of capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, gauss-law

[image]

It is said that second conductor reduces the potential of fist conductor and hence increases charge taking ability of first conductor

My confusion...
As per my limited knowledge it is electric field which causes breakdown. In first case electric field is small and hence less chance of air breakdown. But in second case electric field is more and hence greater chance of dielectric (air) breakdown. 
So how second conductor helps if we think this way ?

Comment: The first case is not even physical. The entire charge would be sitting on both sides of the conductor. The only way you can get a charge distribution as shown in the first place is with an insulator. Dielectric breakdown only happens if the fields become too strong. Solid dielectrics can handle much larger fields than gases and they have internal atomic or molecular polarization, which increases capacitance considerably.

Comment: @CuriousOne :   Assume dielectric to be air. 

As per above diagram clearly we can give more charge to first conductor in first case because E.F is less and chance of dielectric breakdown is lesser

Comment: The dielectric breakdown is always (roughly) the same because it's a material property. How much charge one needs to cause it, that's geometry dependent, especially around objects with sharp tips.

Comment: *"It is said that second conductor reduces the potential of fist conductor and hence increases charge taking ability of first conductor"* - reference?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think in terms of potential . Consider the first plate, say $A$. It can be charged to a maximum value $+Q$ since any further increase in charge will cause a leakage of charge due to the increase in potential. You can imagine that. The potential of a charge distribution decreases slowly than the electric field with distance. So we need no leakage of charge. Now, we place another plate, say $B$, in the vicinity of $A$. The face of $B$ close to $A$ will earn a negative charge same as the positive charge in magnitude. So that face earns a negative charge $-Q$. by induction. This $-Q$ charge on one of the faces of $B$ induce a positive charge of same magnitude as that of negative charge on the other face of $B$. Hence the other face of $B$ earns a charge $+Q$.  The negative charge on $B$ try to decrease the potential of $A$. At the same time, the positive charge on $B$ try to increase the potential of A. But the effect of the negative charge on the closer face of $B$ w.r.t. $A$ will be higher. So the potential of A reduces.

Now we ground B. The excess positive charge on $B$ flows to the ground and on that face, develops a negative charge. This more negative charge enables $A$ to hold more positive charge. this is the principle of a capacitor. Since the charge on the pate increased, the effective capacity to store charges in the plate is increased. Also the electric field is increased.

You can also see that the electric force between the two plates is attractive. So the potential energy of the charge configuration should decrease as attractive forces are more stable. Dielectric break down means a long reduction in the resistance of an electrical insulator when the voltage applied across it exceeds the breakdown voltage. This results in the insulator becoming electrically conductive. However, in this configuration, the voltage between the plates is reduced. So there is no chance of dielectric breakdown.

Comment: Kindly help me think in electric field way as I have posted

Comment: @Aman, the electric field produced by a charged plate is constant and is independent of distance. The dielectric breakdown is explained on the basis of voltage applied across the dielectric material.

Comment: Two opposite charges attract. Attraction is more stable than repulsion. Work is done to keep two like charges at a finite distance due to electrostatic repulsion. This work is stored as the potential energy of the system. Now, the work is done by the electrostatic forces itself, if we have two unlike charges. No external work is needed. So the potential energy of the system is reduced. Reduced potential energy corresponds to a more stable state. In our case, the potential is defined as the potential energy per unit charge. So, if potential energy decreases potential also decrease.

Comment: As per books dielectric breakdown of air takes place when electric field through it exceeds 3 x 10 ^ 6  V/m which is called dielectric strength

Comment: Yes, if the electric field is varying with distance. But in the case of capacitor arrangement, for a given charge on the plates the electric field in between the plates at any point is a constant. It can be verified from your equation for electric field. It does not depend on any distance terms. Here in the data, now you provided, the electric field strength is defined as potential per distance. So, here also potential is the star player

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. Whether electric field is constant or not, Problem is E.F is responsible for dielectric breakdown. In first case E.F is lesser and hence it can hold more charge before breakdown than second case.  so main motive of keeping second plate near it is ?

Comment: See Aman, the electric field is nothing but the potential per unit distance (it's unit is V/m). As you can see the value of E.F increased twice as that in the case of first arrangement. Electric field is proportional to the charge in the plate. With the parallel plate arrangement of same dimension, we can have twice as charge than in a single plate. A single plate cannot store charge. When you place a negatively charged plate in the vicinity of a positively charged one, the electric field is confined to exist in between the plates and will be the sum of electric field due to individual plates.

Comment: Dielectric breakdown refers to emit the electrons in a dielectric material, making it conductive. The application of electric field accelerates the charge. If the applied field is so high, then dielectric breakdown occurs. The electric field flows from positive to negative plate. Due to the dielectric property of the medium, the medium itself develops an opposite electric field. The electric field in the dielectric will be greater than the external field. So it resists dielectric breakdown. But using a single plate, the electric field is less and so dielectric field also decreases